# Testing if a web service API is RESTful

Tags: web-services, rest, testing

One of the technical requirements of the software I am working on is to provide a REST web service API.

As a consequence, I am now asked to create a manual or automated test checking if the software provides a REST web service API.

My initial thought is that this is not possible, as REST is not formally defined and is not a protocol. Some might even say that my API is not RESTful.

Is there any way for me to provide such a test?

Comment: Maybe someone has developed such a tool (I doubt it) - if not, you could be its author :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that, as you said, REST is not formally defined, I think you'd need to go to the requirements writer and ask them what satisfies their criteria for being RESTful.

Comment: From a process point of view, I think that's actually the only reasonable thing to do.